# How can 10 tons of thrust keep a 100 ton aircraft in the air?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I think the reasons are as follows:

We all know that on an inclined plane, we can lift an object by a force much smaller than its weight. The same is true of airplanes, which are also on inclined planes and lift themselves into the sky with a small force.

This inclined plane is made up of wings and air. One is the wing inclined plane, the other is the air inclined plane. The wing has an angle of attack, so the wing is an inclined plane. Air flows through the surface of the wing, so air is in fact an invisible inclined plane. The air inclined plane consists of two parts, one is the air inclined plane at the bottom of the wing and the other is the air inclined plane at the top of the wing.

The bearing capacity of an inclined plane is determined by the material of the wing. The bearing capacity of air inclined plane is determined by the relative speed of air and wing. Under the condition of no stall, the greater the relative speed, the greater the bearing capacity of the air inclined plane, and the heavier the air inclined plane can bear.

The angle of inclined plane is related to the angle of attack, but not necessarily equal to the angle of attack. If the angle of attack is too large, the air inclined plane on the top of the wing will be destroyed. In this way, the support of air inclined plane will be greatly reduced.

Am I wrong? Why?

Comment: According to the title of the question, the lift = 100 & the drag = 10. Why do you think that's a problem? Lift/drag ratios of 10 are pretty common.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think it saves energy with inclined plane. What do you think?

Comment: If a plane had a thrust >= it's weight then it would be a VTOL craft.

Comment: @D.Halsey Why can we use 10 tons of thrust to generate 100 tons of lift?

Comment: @ enbin zheng The aircraft uses the thrust to accelerate to a speed that allows the wings to produce sufficient lift. Then it keeps moving forward to maintain the lift. It could not lift 100 tons if it was just hovering. (assuming a conventional aircraft).

Comment: @D.Halsey Why can we use 10 tons of thrust to generate 100 tons of lift?

Comment: [Due diligence](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/ldrat.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are big differences between pushing a block on an inclined plane and pushing aircraft to climb in the atmosphere.

Wooden block on an inclined plane can stay there indefinitely because of static friction, and when it is pushed by external force upwards, the whole motion can be done as slowly as possible; the supporting plane is always there. The block does not have to move at all to experience support force from the inclined plane. Also, the external force pushing the block does not have to have any component that would lift the block above the plane of motion.

The aircraft motion dynamics is more complicated: to achieve enough lift force, it needs to move with some minimal speed with respect to the air, otherwise the lift is insufficient. The lift is not due to inclined plane of any sort, but due to fact that air is being pushed downwards by the plane, both by the jet engines and by the wings. The thrust force of the engines alone is not sufficient to lift the plane against gravity, but the additional thrust force due to wings pushing the air down makes total lift greater than the weight of the plane. It is an aerodynamics process, not a statics process.

Comment: For wood blocks, inclined planes are original, they do not need to be generated by the movement of wood blocks; for aircraft, air inclined planes must be generated by relative motion. In addition, in the inclined plane without friction, we can also push the block up.